# Implement java map accessed by multiple threads that is only updated once for each key

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

I need to create a Map that will be accessed by multiple threads and that only ever has one (not null) value inserted in it.

To clarify what I'm trying to do :

```
Object getValue(key)  
    {  
        if(map.get(key) != null)  
           return map.get(key)  
        else  
        {   
           Object obj = new Object();  
           map.put(key, obj);  
           return obj;   
        }   
    }
```

The easiest way would be to make the getValue method synchronised, but I want to make the method as efficient as possible, so actually my requirement is to put the 'else' part in a synchronised block , locked somehow on the 'key' value. What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use one of the concurrent collections?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want the computeIfAbsent method.

```
// support a map which allows concurrent access.
ConcurrentMap<Key,Value> map = ....

Value onePerKey = map.computeIfAbsent(key, Value::new);
```

or

```
Value onePerKey = map.computeIfAbsent(key, key -> new Value());
```

---

from the Javadoc for [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

> The default implementation is equivalent to the following steps for
>   this map, then returning the current value or null if now absent:
>
> ```
> if (map.get(key) == null) {
>   V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
>   if (newValue != null)
>      return map.putIfAbsent(key, newValue);
> }
> ```
>
> The default implementation may retry these steps when multiple threads attempt updates including potentially calling the mapping
>   function multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "The default implementation may retry these steps when multiple threads attempt updates including potentially calling the mapping function multiple times." - this is what I'm afraid of, because i can only create one map entry for a key. The same object must be used by all threads

Comment: @Shipra the same object will be used by all threads even if the factory is called more than once. The redundant values are discarded.